# Renewal of expat driving licence now living in Greece and over 70, what to do?

Tags: driving-license, uk-citizens, greece

Can anyone please advise on the procedure for my renewal i.e. based on the title the renewal form is not so clear as in such the declaration states " resident in UK"
What to do?
John

Answer (score 3):

If you are living in Greece, then EU law expects you to renew your license in the country of your residence. So that's what you should do.

Comment: In case someone reads this years from now: this may change after Brexit.

Comment: @gerrit it may, but it doesn't seem likely.  Most jurisdictions expect people to be licensed where they reside.

Comment: @phoog Only if they're planning to drive locally.  The OP does not specify this.  When I lived in Canada, I did not drive locally, but I did have the option of renewing my Dutch license with the Dutch authorities.  Living in the UK I do not have this option because of EU law.

Comment: @gerrit that's true; one must consider both the licensing jurisdiction and the jurisdiction of residence (which is more or less irrelevant if one never drives there).  Another consideration: in some jurisdictions, renewing your driver's license when you live elsewhere may be taken as evidence that you are maintaining a domicile in the jurisdiction and are therefore subject to taxation on your worldwide income.